# `git push origin master` does not work

Tags: git

I cloned a remote repo using (vars names changed--**I have to hide the URL because of security purposes.**)

```
git clone -b someLocalRepo github.com/someRemoteRepo.git someLocalRepo
```

(unsure what the `-b` flag is for if I specified at the end what I want the repo to be named as on my computer...)

Made some changes and then did

```
git add -A
git commit -m "testing git"
```

I read online that I'm supposed to do `git push origin master` but it throws me the following error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/someRemoteRepo.git'
```

I did several searches but could not figure out why. Can someone explain what's going on here?

**Note:** git push and git push origin works

Comment: What branch are you on? If not specified, you are defaulting to `master`, check your branch with `git branch`, then do `git push origin <output of previous>`

Comment: I wonder if the remote repo was created such that the main branch is not 'master'. Try 'git branch -r' to see the branches of the remote repo.

Comment: I don't understand the title - `git push origin` *does* and at the same time *does not* work?

Comment: @MichaelEaster hi, what do you mean the main branch is not 'master'? could you define main branch and master?

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry I fixed the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clone -b someLocalRepo` means "clone the repository and check out that named branch". And this is exactly your problem — your repository doesn't have branch `someLocalRepo` so you're not on any branch now.

To fix that check out an existing branch. Let's try `master`:

```
cd someLocalRepo
git checkout master
```

Now `git push origin` should work.

Comment: could you define main branch and master?

Comment: You can name branches any way you want. When `git init` or `clone` a repository default branch is `master` but you can rename it, create other branches, even remove `master` and use any name you prefer.